# regex multiple string in a list c#

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have a problem in my script.
I just want to show some parts with Regex.

```
string str = "db_name=Killa db_type=0 db_sync=false db_id=12 db_status=offline|db_name=mcHD db_type=0 db_sync=true db_id=28 db_status=online|db_name=sla db_type=0 db_sync=false db_id=193 db_status=online";
var l = string.Join("|", str);
var reg = Regex.Matches(l, @"db_name=(.+?)\s+db_id=(\d+)\s+db_status=(.+?)").Cast<Match>().Select(a => new
{
    db_name = a.Groups[1].Value,
    db_id = a.Groups[2].Value,
    db_status = a.Groups[3].Value
}).ToList();
foreach (var x in reg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.db_name + " " + x.db_id + " " + x.db_status);
}
```

But this does not give what I want back, but this data.

```
Killa db_type=0 db_sync=false 12 o
mcHD db_type=0 db_sync=true 28 o
sla db_type=0 db_sync=false 193 o
```

And that's what I want:

```
Killa 12 offline
mcHD 28 online
sla 193 online
```

I hope I get an answer and thanks for the help.

Comment: And what does this line do `var l = string.Join("|", str)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to

```
db_name=(\w+)[^|]+db_id=(\d+)[^|]+db_status=(\w+)
```

And will get what you want

Comment: Thank you, it worked!  
Edit: Can you maybe explain why it did not work ??

Comment: @mariaLynx first your mistake is in `db_name=(.+?)\s+db_id`. Let's look closely on the middle part `(.+?)\s+`. Will start from the end of this part. `\s+` can take only the whitespaces before `db_id` and nothing more. So `(.+?)` should take the rest text starting after `db_name=` and ending just before the whitespaces before `db_id`. Now the second mistake is in `db_status=(.+?)`. `(.+?)` will take any character and will take at least one character and will take it lazily, so it will take only ONE character(, because it's lazy).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does exactly what you tell it to do:

```
@"db_name=(.+?)\s+db_id=(\d+)\s+db_status=(.+?)"
```

This takes everything between `db_name` until the space before `db_id`. But in the input string, you have also db_type an db_sync between those 2 fields.

If you change to this regex, it works like you want:

```
@"db_name=(?<name>.+?)\s+db_type=(?<type>\d+)\s+db_sync=(?<sync>true|false)\sdb_id=(?<id>\d+)\s+db_status=(?<status>[^|]+)"
```

This also captures db_type and db_sync, so you have to adjust your code to

```
db_name = a.Groups[1].Value,
db_id = a.Groups[4].Value,
db_status = a.Groups[5].Value
```

Or, since I used [named groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression):

```
db_name = a.Groups["name"].Value,
db_id = a.Groups["id"].Value,
db_status = a.Groups["status"].Value
```

However. I seriously doubt that this is the proper way to solve your underlying problem. Where does the original data come from? Why are you using regular expressions?

Comment: I want to use this as a List () to make it easier for example:
`x.db_name` or `x.db_id` or `x.db_status`  
With the pattern of you comes out another output:
`Killa false 12
mcHD true 28
sla false 193`

Comment: or is there a simpler method?

Comment: I made a mistake, fixed

Comment: As for whether there is a simpler method: where does the data originally come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
var list =
        from z in str.Split('|')
        let x = z.Split(' ')
        let p1 = x[0].Split('=')[1]
        let p2 = x[3].Split('=')[1]
        let p3 = x[4].Split('=')[1]
        select string.Join(' ', p1, p2, p3);
```